# What does this yum command mean?

Tags: yum

Can someone explain what is the meaning of `git` in the following command? Or, any other option instead of `git`?

```
sudo yum install -y git vim-enhanced
```

Comment: You should be careful about running “sudo” commands that you don’t understand. It’s a good thing you’re asking first! What is your goal with the command?

Comment: I'm trying to install vim and following online course with linuxacademy.com for python scripting. Why I Can't just run the command like "sudo yum install vim-enhanced" instead of "git" option

Comment: At least they’re having you install a decent editor :)

Comment: As another point of commentary, I would suggest that the -y come after yum but before install, as it’s an option to yum, not a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` is a software to fetch source code of software or any other files from GitHub. It can download a particular git url as follows

```
git clone url
```

While fetching `git` keeps the directory structure and properties like executable etc. intact.

For more details hit `man git` (after installation only) and visit through its manual.

The command you've mentioned will install two software `git` and `vim-enhanced` along with additional components. Both are safe. But never run `sudo` command without knowing. And the `-y` flag with `yum` instruct a direct installation without further communication.

Comment: Git's primary goal is to develop and (arguably) to publish software, but not to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` : Run the following command as root. On linux systems you need admin's privileges to install packages, and root is the admin user's name.

`yum` : Software for managing software packages on redhat based systems (usually)

`install` : Using the above tool, please install the following packages

`-y` : ..and please do it without bothering asking to confirm the installation.

`git` : This is the first packages to install (see other answers about what git is)

`vim-enhanced` : this is the second package to install

Also:

Remove `-y` makes `yum` asking if you really want to proceed with packages' installation. If you add `-q` yum goes really silent.. showing no output at all.

Using `search` instead of `install` will ask `yum` to search for the mentioned packages (`git` and `vim-enhanced` in this case), showing you what exactly are they for.

You can add any number of packages after those 2, to install them in one go

More on yum: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html

And Thank you, [Seth Vidal](https://www.redhat.com/fr/blog/thank-you-seth-vidal).

Answer (score 0):

**git** is version control software (program), created by the Linux created - Linus Torvalds:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-git

Answer (score 0):

The real meaning of git in that command is that is just one of the package names that is about to be installed by `yum install`.

Answer (score -1):

git is version control software (program), On your command, you try to install git and vim editor in Red Hat.